# Pages and posts with Rel Canonical issues across entire site

Tags: seo

SEOmoz is showing that a number of my sites have issues with Rel Canonical which they describe as "Using rel=canonical suggests to search engines which URL should be seen as canonical." I'm using Yoast's SEO plugin but I'm unsure what would cause this error.

Is it a result of something having to do with renaming pages or changing the permalinks? If so, how would I resolve it?

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps

Comment: What is the actual error. Just suggesting to use rel=Canonical is is not an error.

Comment: They're actually titling it as an issue not an error. I'm not quite sure what is causing the Rel=Canonical.

Answer (score 1):

I've spoken to the SEOmoz guys about this, it's not an error nor an "issue" and they're making the appropriate changes to their system to reflect that.